# "Unable to access page" error on login

Tags: login-errors

> Unable to Access Page
>
> The value of the "icid" parameter contains a character that is not
>   allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the
>   character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and
>   resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer
>   Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well
>   as any other related information.

I'm getting this error when trying to log in to SFDC. Anyone have any ideas of what might be causing it or how to fix it? Otherwise I'm imagining a few days before I get a response from SFDC support.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies? This post seems to indicate it will help, although it's not marked as a solution, and I haven't experienced it. http://forums.sforce.com/t5/Security/Invalid-quot-icid-quot-parameter-in-spring-13-sandbox-login-url/m-p/556665/highlight/true#M1912

Comment: I deleted out all the parts of the various SFDC cookies from Chrome and that seemed to do the trick, thanks. Add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like other users have reported this on the Developer Boards, see: [Invalid "icid" parameter in spring 13 sandbox login url syntax](http://forums.sforce.com/t5/Security/Invalid-quot-icid-quot-parameter-in-spring-13-sandbox-login-url/m-p/556665/highlight/true#M1912).

It appears clearing your cookies will resolve the issue.

> "That will generally happen when you have corrupted cookies.  Go to
>   your browser's cookies and delete anything salesforce related.  Then
>   attempt to log in again." - [Steve Fischer](http://forums.sforce.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/85105)